# Need to install and uninstall dependencies in Webstorm from package.json

Tags: node.js, webstorm

How can you get Webstorm to install all node modules listed in package.json and remove any node modules not listed there?

Comment: currently you have to use terminal for this. Please vote for [WEB-8776](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-8776) for a possibility to do this from WebStorm UI

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can open terminal window inside WebStorm and then run npm commands from there.

To install packages mentioned in package.json:

```
npm install
```

To remove extraneous packages

```
npm prune
```

Comment: Well that was simple and yet disappointing, wish they integrated a few npm in a project menu... does anyone know if a plugin for this?

Comment: You can add it as an "external tool" and then it can be a pre-run step in your run configurations, that's what I did.